# Practical Uses for DoubleAdder in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, atomic

I'm learning moreover multithreading. While going through AtomicInteger, AtomicBoolean etc... seen that there is one class named [DoubleAdder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/DoubleAdder.html)

Like AtomicInteger can be used by many threads concurrently. When we are using an 'AtomicInteger' variable in the multi-threaded environment we don't need 'synchronized' & 'volatile' keywords as atomic integers take care of thread safety.

**Can someone please elaborate use cases of [DoubleAdder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/DoubleAdder.html) class?**

Comment: The documentation actually includes a good use case for it which you can extrapolate on and consider for other use cases; `This class is usually preferable to alternatives when multiple threads update a common value that is used for purposes such as summary statistics that are frequently updated but less frequently read.`

Comment: @Jason This sounds like a generic statement, I wanna understand some specific use cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AtomicInteger, AtomicLong and all other Atomic variables will often share a single cache line for updates. That means each time a write occurs, all threads using the same Atomic object will have a cache-invalidation which will force whatever slowdown is required to synchronize.

In systems where you concurrent add a lot, and a system where you are not dependent on the values to be exactly accurate, then a DoubleAdder is best. Each thread has their own adder object it is incrementing (allowing each thread to not invalidate another thread). At the end you can ask the DoubleAdder for the sum of all thread's incrementing values.

The most common use case one can think of to use a DoubleAdder is metrics or statistics. Often you need good-enough tracking of metrics but don't often need exact precision.

At the very end, when all threads have stopped, if you were to ask the DoubleAdder for the sum of all threads, then you will get 100% accuracy.

Comment: After reading your answer, I'm confusing myself with ThreadLocal.

Comment: Yes, you can! It's very similar to a `ThreadLocal`. It's really a specialized ThreadLocal that handles adding/subtracting of primitives in a more optimized way than just using a ThreadLocal directly. Main purpose here is throughput.

Comment: `ThreadLocal` has no method to iterate over the existing values nor to aggregate them. The key point of `DoubleAdder` is that only the accumulation is performed on different variables (and only if contention makes it necessary), while the ultimate goal still is to produce a single end result. That’s what you get for free when using `parallel().sum()` on a `DoubleStream`.